# SCSS color preview in WebStorm

Tags: sass, webstorm

[image]

In WebStorm color preview works well. But when they come into the value of scss variables, color preview doesn't works any more.

Is there any plugin or hack for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6015 -- watch this and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.